# What's the memory hit of an identical constant string assigned to every object of a typescript class?

Tags: typescript

It would be a giant help if we can have a className member variable in every object that is a class we created in typescript. That will make it a piece of cake to identify the object's class safely.

It has to be a member variable (not an ES5 get/set) because we pass these objects across to/from a web worker and so only the data comes across.

We would declare the string for the name as a static in each class and assign that static. So the memory hit should be just 1 more pointer per instantiated object.

Is there any downside to doing this aside from the memory due to the additional pointer in each object?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just put it on the prototype? Then there's only one pointer and guaranteed to be only one instance of the string.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh the problem is we need this going across when we post messages to/form a web worker and that only carries data across, not the prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing a string in a single memory location based on its value i.e. same value gets you the *exact same memory location* is called **String Interning**.

Good browsers (chrome ;)) do implement string interning. Here is a test for string interning with results for various browsers : http://jsperf.com/strinterning

In the absence of string interning you get a new memory address + allocation. The quantity of memory will depend upon *your* usage but if you are wondering, string allocation is not a ***specially*** slow process in JavaScript. Its the same as in say C# (which does have interning btw ... we are discussing different strings that need allocation now).